# How to get how many minutes the user is idle by using user lastActivity?

Tags: mysql, sql

Im using PhpMyadmin Mysql

this is my sql record from database, How can I use timediff to subtract NOW(); from last activity which is user is user1 and get how many minutes user1 is idle.

```
id   lastActivity           user
1    2015-05-08 00:20:40    user1
2    2015-05-08 00:32:29    user2
```

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: Can you share what queries you have tried? Also, what "flavor" of SQL are you using? SQL Server, SQLite, Oracle, postgre, etc?

Comment: SELECT TIMEDIFF('lastActivity','NOW()') FROM users WHERE id = 1   result is 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, lastActivity, NOW()) FROM .....
```

Comment: but it will output number, how to output in minutes

Comment: the number is the minutes(use MINUTE as first argument), which format do you want it to be?